# Should I used "submits" or "submitted" after "We used to wait"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sequence-of-tenses

I have one confusion with one sentence structure. We know that we can use any tense with present tense, future tense and past for only past. But in this case I am really confused. If someone told me about this, that would be really helpful.

> We used to wait till someone brave submits his exam papers.

Is it ok or I should have used "submitted" instead of submit?

Comment: You are referring to a situation in the past, so you should have used _submitted_. _Submits_ would only apply if you were still waiting!

Comment: For your information, we generally say: to hand in an exam paper. You submit a paper (study, article) to a publication, but you **hand in your exam paper to the examiner**.

Comment: @Lambie Actually situation is we were in the middle of the exam and you couldn't write a single word so we waited to submit. But you know that was embarrassing cause you could easily get noticed. So we waited for someone who would do it first and we would follow him. This is the situation and I wanted to express as our past habitude. So here the sentence comes,  "We used to wait till someone brave submits his exam papers." and I am bit confused that if it was grammatically correct or wrong. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @KateBunting Actually situation is we were in the middle of the exam and you couldn't write a single word so we waited to submit. But you know that was embarrassing cause you could easily get noticed. So we waited for someone who would do it first and we would follow him. This is the situation and I wanted to express as our past habitude. So here the sentence comes, "We used to wait till someone brave submits his exam papers." and I am bit confused that if it was grammatically correct or wrong. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: There is no submit or submission here. We say: ***hand in exam papers***.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _we were in the middle of the exam and you couldn't write a single word_. Are you saying that half the time allowed for the exam had passed and no-one had started to write? In any case, for something that happened in the past it has to be _we used to wait until someone submitted his papers_.